# XSLT: nested for-each and dynamic variable

Tags: xslt

This is my XML and XSLT code

```
<root>
    <act>
        <acts id>123</acts>
    </act>
    <comp>
        <comps id>233</comps>
    </comp>
</root>


<xsl:for-each select="act/acts">
    <xsl:variable name="contactid" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/comp/comps">
        <xsl:variable name="var" select="boolean(contactid=@id)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$var='true'">
          . . . do this . . .
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          . . . do that . . .
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to dynamically assign true or false to `var` and use it inside `<xsl:choose>` for boolean test. I hope this helps to find a better solution to get rid of `for-each` also

Comment: There is something wrong in your XML - the `id` attributes have no values - should `123` and `233` be the value of the `id` attributes - or are they the content of the node (and in such a case `id` should have some other value)?

Comment: `var` should be true if ANY `comps` have an id equal to the one of the current `acts`?

Comment: <root>
    <act><acts id="123"></acts></act>
    <comp><comps id="233"></comps></comp>
</root>
ya this is what i meant sorry for that..

Comment: yes var should be true if any comps have an id equal to the one of the current acts

Comment: It's much more effective to describe your problem in terms of the input and desired output rather than in terms of code that doesn't solve the problem. Working out what people intended from code that isn't legal in the chosen language can be quite difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to note is that variables in XSLT are immutable, and cannot be changed once initialised. The main problem with your XSLT is that you define your variable within an **xsl:for-each** block and so it only exists within the scope of that block. It is not a global variable. A new variable gets defined each time that can only be used within the **xsl:for-each**

From looking at your XSLT it looks like you want to iterate over the **acts** element and perform a certain action depending on whether an **comps** element exists with the same value. An alternative approach would be to define a key to look up the **comps** elements, like so

```
<xsl:key name="comps" match="comps" use="@id" />
```

Then you can simply check whether a **comps** element exists like so (assuming you are positioned on an **acts** element.

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="key('comps', @id)">Yes</xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="comps" match="comps" use="@id" />

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="act/acts" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="acts">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="key('comps', @id)"><res>Yes</res></xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise><res>No</res></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following (well-formed) XML

```
<root>
   <act>
      <acts id="123"/>
   </act>
   <comp>
      <comps id="233"/>
   </comp>
</root>
```

The following is output

No

However, it can often be preferably in XSLT to avoid the use of conditional statements like **xsl:choose** and **xsl:if**. Instead, you can structure the XSLT to make use of template matching. Here is the alternate approach

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="comps" match="comps" use="@id" />

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="act/acts" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="acts[key('comps', @id)]">
      <res>Yes</res>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="acts">
      <res>No</res>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the same XML, the same result is output. Do note the more specific template for the **acts** node will take priority when matching the case where a **comps** exist.

Comment: thank you so much for the solution, i tried with xsl:choose and yet to try for the second one..

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your xml file, but assuming what you mean is:

```
<root>
    <act><acts id="123"></acts></act>
    <comp><comps id="233"></comps></comp>
</root>
```

Here is a full solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <doc>   
           <xsl:apply-templates select="root/comp/comps"/>  
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/comp/comps"> 
        <xsl:variable name="compsid" select="@id"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(/root/act/acts[@id=$compsid])&gt;0">Do This</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Do That</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: but i want to use this inside a for loop as i posted the code, for each acts id i will check for a similar comps id

Comment: Updated my answer to include the full solution.

Comment: This solution looks fine to me - except that it checks which `comps` have an `acts` with the same id - it should be the opposite I think, but it is easy to change.

Comment: `count(/root/act/acts[@id=$compsid])&gt;0` can be written more simply as `/root/act/acts[@id=$compsid])` (an expression that returns nodes is true if it contains at least one node).

Comment: I'm amazed that anyone should even try to solve your problem when you've given no indication of the desired output, and I'm not remotely surprised that they appear to have solved a different problem from the one you were trying to solve.

Comment: thanks every one who tried to help me out...and @micheal i thought the xsl code itself which was small said the intended output