# XSLT field validation

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to validate a field content which is within a 1..N structure, so the data come in pairs of RESULT_ID and RESULT_VALUE.

If "<" is found in Result.Min_Limit characteristic, its value must be put in the Max_Limit characteristic target field and Min_Limit must be cleared out in target structure.

Sample of source structure with data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
    <RESULTS>
           <RESULT>
                <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.Derived</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE>59W</D_RESULT_VALUE>
            </D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.Min_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE>&lt;=600.0000</D_RESULT_VALUE>
            </D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.Max_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE/>
            </D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.FailedCriticalLvl</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE>false</D_RESULT_VALUE>
            </D_RESULT>
       </RESULT>
  </RESULTS>
</TEST>
```

Expected target structure should be as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
  <RESULTS>
       <RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.Derived</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE>59W</D_RESULT_VALUE>
            </D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.Min_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE/>
            </D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.Max_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE>&lt;=600.0000</D_RESULT_VALUE>
            </D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT>
                 <D_RESULT_ID>Result.FailedCriticalLvl</D_RESULT_ID>
                 <D_RESULT_VALUE>false</D_RESULT_VALUE>
            </D_RESULT>
       </RESULT>
  </RESULTS>
</TEST>
```

I've created a variable to store Min_Limit value if it contains the "<" character, and it works fine when the pointer is still in Min_Limit characteristic.
When it flips to next characteristic (Max_Limit), the variable seems to loose its value and therefore I have no visibility of Min_Limit value anymore to assign the value to Max_Limit characteristic.

Currently, what I have is like the following:

......

```
    <xsl:for-each select="a:D_RESULT">
        <D_RESULT>
            <D_RESULT_ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="a:D_RESULT_ID"/>
            </D_RESULT_ID>
            <D_RESULT_VALUE>
                <xsl:value-of select="a:D_RESULT_VALUE"/>
            </D_RESULT_VALUE>
        </D_RESULT>
    </xsl:for-each>
</RESULT>
```

... other fields

I've found some interesting conversations here with some approaches I believe would help solving this, but I'm not sure I understood enough to apply to my scenario.
This is one of those [XSLT: nested for-each and dynamic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215815/xslt-nested-for-each-and-dynamic-variable)

Would anyone suggests something to solve this?

Many thanks in advance!
Rafael.

Comment: Good question, but include your code! Good luck.

Comment: Why does your code use a prefix when the XML is in no namespace?

Comment: It is in a namespace. I've hidden it since I thought it was not relevant to this post. The stylesheet 1st tag is as follow: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://www.mycompany.com/SYS/SCENARIO/VERSION/2.8" xmlns:map="java:java.util.Map" xmlns:dyn="java:com.sap.aii.mapping.api.DynamicConfiguration" xmlns:key="java:com.sap.aii.mapping.api.DynamicConfigurationKey" xmlns:javamap="java:com.xom.xi.common.util.DateConversion">

Comment: You shouldn't change the entire question - it may invalidate any answers already given. It would be better to ask a new question instead.

Comment: =( alright, I've just posted a new one. Sorry for the mess. Hope you can give some help on the new post. Tks.

Comment: @RafaVieira I have rolled your question back to the what it was when I answered it. Since you've opened a new question, consider closing this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="D_RESULT_VALUE[../D_RESULT_ID='Result.Min_Limit' and contains(., '&lt;')] ">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="D_RESULT_VALUE[../D_RESULT_ID='Result.Max_Limit' and contains(../../D_RESULT[D_RESULT_ID='Result.Min_Limit']/D_RESULT_VALUE, '&lt;')] ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../D_RESULT[D_RESULT_ID='Result.Min_Limit']/D_RESULT_VALUE"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtA

Comment: Michael, I'm sure it helps to solve my issue, however I don't have much idea of where/how to include this solution in the already existing code. Should these templates be placed inside the XML tag, should it replace the tag? I'm sure this would be very basic for you, sorry for such questions a too-basic questions. I'll read a bit more to better understand the usage of template and other language features, but for now if you could provide a brief detail of how to do this change, I'd really appreciate since it's a problem I'm facing in production environment.

Comment: This is a *complete* stylesheet - no additional code is necessary. if your current code performs other functions, please edit your question and explain that (and please don't post code in comments - no one can read it).

Comment: I've changed the whole question. Hopefully you could give a hand one more time. Tks Michael!

Comment: @RafaVieira Is this question not answered?

Comment: A little bit late but... yes, it's answered!